# Nexus S 4G (SCH-i515) "This item cannot be installed in your country"

Tags: android, google-play

I can't download my application from **Google play** on *Samsung Nexus S 4G (SCH-i515)*. **Google play** tell that **"This item cannot be installed in your country"**.[image]

Device is from US, but is used in Ukraine and with Ukraine IP adresses.

In the Developer console I've selected Ukraine only for the app.

My manifest settings are:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"/>
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Does I must to change something in the Manifest or I must change some settings on the device?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play doesn't check your GPS or network location, it just looks at which carrier you're using. On GSM phones the information from the SIM card is used to determine your carrier. Since you have a CDMA Galaxy Nexus (Verizon, I guess?) and swapping out the SIM card for a Ukrainian one isn't an option, your phone probably still shows up as a US Verizon device.

Basically, you'll have to change the carrier information stored on the phone somehow. There's an app called Market Enabler that will let you change the network code, but I'm not sure whether it will work with recent Android/Play versions. List of network codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Code#U).

Comment: Official Google quote: "The app will only be visible to the countries (carriers) that you select, as follows:

A device's country is determined based on the carrier, if a carrier is available. If no carrier can be determined, Google Play tries to determine the country based on IP.
Carrier is determined based on the device's SIM (for GSM devices), not the current roaming carrier."

Comment: Operator - Intertelecom, but how can I determine country that my device gives? CDMA doesn't give MCC data.
If my country isn't Ukraine, than I can go to the technical support of Intertelecom (where I bought this device) and ask them to fix it. But I must to know country that my device gives, for this.